# Accessing all methods from es6 class from another one

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have 2 classes: MyClass and CBook. I would like to have access to all functions and variables of MyClass class from the CBook class. How can i do that ?

**MyClass**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import {CBook} from './book';

const path = "http://www.mypage.com";

class MyClass {

    constructor() {
        let _summaryPageUI = new CBook(this);
    }

    describeBook() {
        console.log('test');
    }

}

new MyClass();

export {MyClass};
```

I would like to have access to all methods from MyClass in CBook:

**CBook**

```
class CBook {
    constructor(myClass) {
        console.log(myClass);
    }
}

export {CBook};
```

Comment: If your purpose is both classes share methods, to use an interface pattern approach.

Comment: You have access to all methods and properties of that instance of MyClass. What more do you want? And most important, why?

Comment: Globally, i would be able to call any method of MyClass from the CBook class. In my example, i pass 'this' in the constructor but maybe it's not the good solution ?

Comment: Just use `myClass.describeBook()` (and anything else) in the `CBook` constructor? It's unclear what you mean by "have access to". Please post some example code of how you would like to use the classes and what outputs you expect from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the extends property.  See documentation at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends

or
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

```
class myClass extends CBook {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log("MyClass instantiated");
  }
  describeBook() {
    console.log("book described");
  }
}


class CBook extends MyClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("CBook instantiated");
  }
}
```

You then will be able to do:

```
const book = new CBook();
book.describeBook();
```

You will get output:

`MyClass instantiated

CBook instantiated

book described`

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is a function that is immediately called when a new instance of the class (object) is created. This initializes the objects initial properties and state. As XPX-Gloom noted, you use the extends keyword to implicitly say "CBook object, take either all or some of the properties of MyClass when instantiated". By using super(), you are calling the constructor of MyClass. This 'super' keyword is for making super-constructor calls and allows access to parent methods.
[example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/)

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 all class instance methods are public so you can access them all by creating an instance of `MyClass` and calling it's methods like this:

```
class CBook {
  constructor(myClass) {
    this.myClass = myClass;
  }

  someMethod() {
    this.myClass.describeBook()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the terminology you are using "function" - i think you want to define your functions as static,  so that can be called on the class rather than the instance:

define:

```
class foo {
    static someFunc() { console.log("foo:someFunc") }
}
```

Call:

```
foo.someFunc();
```

console out:

```
foo:someFunc
```

for values

add after class definition

```
foo.someValue = "myValue";
```

then:

```
console.log(foo.someValue)
```

will output: myValue